# Escape regex literal in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I have no idea why this isn't working - I've put it through one of the better regex tools I've found on the web to verify it, and I'm using what seems to be the escape character '\' before the + sign to make it a literal '+', but Google Scripts keeps complaining saying "Invalid Quantifier '+'" (Line 2)

Here's my script, with certain personal details (it's to clean out email as I use this account as a hard spam filter) omitted:

```
function getEmailData() {
  var find_email_regex = new RegExp("myemail(\+.*|)\@gmail.com");
  var emails = GmailApp.getChatThreads();
  var process_email = "";
  try {
    for (i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
      for (x = 0; x < emails[i].getTo().length; x++) {
        if (emails[i].getTo()[x].matches(find_email_regex)) {
          email_triage(emails[i]);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {}
}

function email_triage(email) {
  var reject_regex = new RegExp("^[^\+]*$");
  try {
    if (email.matches(reject_regex)) {
      email.moveThreadToTrash();
    }
    else {
      email.getMessages()[0].forward("mymainemail@email.ca");
    }
  } catch (e) {}
}
```

Is there any obvious reason as to why it keeps saying invalid quantifier?
My objective is to regex two variations of my address, since a spammer might send an email with a large list, and I only want to parse my email out of it for further processing.

It needs to handle:
myemail+stuff@gmail.com
myemail@gmail.com

Hence the literal, but I have no luck with it. Please assist, thank you.

Comment: it would be `RegExp("myemail(\\+.*?)?@gmail\\.com");` https://regex101.com/r/fK0aQ7/1

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I believe a disclaimer is in order: `/(x|)/` is not quite equivalent to `(x)?` (in absence of `x`, one captures `""`, one `undefined`). And `((?:x)?)` is a pain :p

Comment: it's based on the language.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: The question is tagged `javascript`. Granted, for OP's purposes, both should work fine, but... future-proofing. Who knows who's reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
RegExp("myemail(\\+.*?|)@gmail\\.com");
                ^    ^  ^      ^^
```

- You need to escape the escape character (double escape for special characters)
- escape the dot before `com`
- and no need to escape `@`
- also make the `.*` non greedy

Answer (score 1):

You need to double escape the `\` as it is a string escape character

```
new RegExp("myemail(\\+.*|)@gmail\\.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

As others say, the string literal is eating your backslash, so regexp is left with none. You can double up on backslashes, or you can use the regexp literal instead of converting a string into a regexp:

```
var find_email_regex = /myemail(\+.*|)@gmail\.com/;
```

Advantage: more legible (and should even be a smidgen faster, given that you are creating only one object instead of two).

Comment: I seem to have found a bunch of regex experts, so since it's related somewhat, is there a way in JS to isolate "randomstuff" from "myemail+randomstuff@gmail.com" without getting the + or @ included in the returned result?